# How to stop all pthreads when one has completed its work?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads, brute-force

I'm trying to create a code to brute-force a random string but running it on one thread makes it take too long (as expected). I'm fiddling around with pthreads and this is what i've come up with:

```
void*
bruteForce ( void* ARGS )
{
    args *arg = ( args * ) ARGS;
    string STRING= arg->STRING;
    string charSet = arg->charSet;
    string guess = arg->guess;

    char c;
    int size;
    int pos;
    int lenght;
    int j = 0;
    char CHAR[STRING.length ( )];
    size = charSet.length ( );

    do
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < STRING.length ( ); j++ )
        {
            pos = rand ( ) % size;
            CHAR[j] = charSet[pos];
            guess = string ( CHAR );
            //cout << guess[j];
        }
        //cout << guess << endl;
    }
    while ( STRING!= guess );

}

int
main ( int argc, char** argv )
{

    srand ( ( unsigned ) ( time ( NULL ) ) );

    const int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 10;

    args arg;
    ifstream myFile;
    string STRING;
    string charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    string guess;

    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    void* status;

    arg.charSet = charSet;
    arg.STRING= STRING;

    char c;
    int size;
    int pos;
    int lenght;
    int j = 0;

    myFile.open ( "string.txt" );

    getline ( myFile, STRING);
    size = charSet.length ( );


    int rc;

    //Creating threads for cracking the string
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        rc = pthread_create ( &threads[i], NULL, bruteForce, ( void* ) &arg );
        if ( rc )
        {
            cout << "Couldnt create thread";
            exit ( 1 );
        }
    }


    //Joining threads
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        rc = pthread_join ( threads[i], &status );
        if ( rc )
        {
            cout << "thread number " << i << " was unable to join: " << rc << endl;
            exit ( 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need someway of signaling that one of the threads has already guessed the string correctly and terminate the others. I read some of the documentation for pthread library and couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I know the brute-force algorithm is by far not the best.

Comment: Once you printed out the result you can just call `exit()`.

Comment: @AntonSavin but where to I call the exit() function?

Comment: From the thread which found the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this much. The exit() function terminates the thread or the whole program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't want your program to run any longer after the answer is found, you can just call [exit(0)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) from the thread which found the answer.

```
do
{
    // ...
}
while ( STRING!= guess );
std::cout << guess << std::endl;
std::exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Clumsy but workable in your case:

Add a DONE flag in global scope.   Set it when a result is found by any thread.
Make each thread's loop be dependent on the flag.

```
 bool DONE=false; // set to true to stop other threads

 void*bruteForce ( void* ARGS )
 {   ...
     do
     {  <try a string>
     }
     while ( !DONE && STRING!= guess );
     DONE=true; // set redundantly but that doesn't hurt
 }
```

Your main program can still do the join to collect finished pthreads, and then continue on with any work it might want to do on the guessed answer.